# i want to scrap text div with flutter

Tags: html, flutter, dart, web-scraping, flutter-dependencies

**i want to select the text div . this is html classes show the picture below please ,in my code i select the parent class all_coll_row and i want to select the children class with index**

[image: this is html classes]

[image: this is my code i select the parent class all_coll_row and i want to select the children class with index 2]

[image: After run my code i show this exception]

Comment: Can you provide the target webpage and one example about what you are trying to get of?

Comment: @ΟυιλιαμΑρκευα i want to get date like that (12:00) and price

Comment: web page's url?